# What is "code golf" on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, code-golf

> #### See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

It seems that someone gives us a problem to solve, tags the question [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) and the winner is whoever completes the solution in the fewest characters. I haven't found a reference for what it is, so lets discuss its purpose here.

EDIT: OK, we've explained what it is, but why stage a competition to see who can use the least number of characters? It's an interesting contest (and that may be the point and I'm looking too deeply) but it doesn't seem to have any other reason. It is *terrible* to read; I think we could have more interesting contests to see who could make the fastest or most flexible or otherwise "best" solution.

Comment: Justifying a game is like explaining a joke is like dissecting a butterfly.

Comment: What is the purpose of sudoku and crosswords?

Comment: @gnibbler to be able to show others how smart I am.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Like in golf where the [low score wins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_play), the fewest amount of characters "wins". While certainly the best solution in every case is not necessarily the solution that has the fewest characters or fewest lines of code, it can be a fun way to exercise your programming muscles. There is even a [Code Golf stack exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, “fewest (key)strokes wins” is exactly what I had in mind when I [coined the phrase](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl.misc/msg/7b97c434492c8d20).

Answer (score 14):

Try to solve the problem using the fewest possible characters of source code.

It's relatively well-known in Perl circles, since Perl's flexibility and terseness make possible very brief solutions to many problems.  In fact, some sources say that code golf originated as "Perl golf".  It's no coincidence that in language-agnostic code golf challenges, a Perl solution is usually the winner.

When the winner uses a language other than Perl, *that* is truly an accomplishment, not only because Perl is naturally suited to this sort of challenge, but because Perl programmers are largely well-acquainted with the game and know the tricks and techniques to golf effectively in their language of choice.

Comment: I do not think that winning solutions in GolfScript are "truly an accomplishment". :-P

Comment: Well, it's at least "kinda" an accomplishment.  It's not like you don't have to think to write a GolfScript solution. ;)

Comment: Writing or understanding GolfScript appears to be less of a challenge than doing the same with J, though. At least in my experience.

Answer (score 8):

shortest->+1

(12 character response)

Answer (score 6):

I like the *atmosphere* of code-golf on SO, The other sites mentioned all have us golf in secret and sometimes never reveal the secret source.

As someone who golfs regularly on SO in 6 or so languages, I find I am sometimes learning useful new things about those languages due to the openness and collaboration that is unique to SO code-golf.

Comment: +1. Heck, I learned many things about a language I'm now using on a daily basis by golfing Project Euler problems in it. It certainly is a great way of finding and trying out even the most obscure language features – not all of them lead to shorter results in all circumstances but you still know tricks you'd otherwise probably never encountered.

Comment: Another comment masquerading as an answer

Answer (score 4):

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ has been in public beta for 11 months.

Answer (score 3):

In the game of [golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf), the player who completes the course with the fewest club strokes wins.  Likewise, code golf is a competition to achieve the specifications in the fewest keystrokes.  It's been popularized on SO and other programming fora, as well as in [organized competitions](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=21442).

Comment: Code golf has been around a long time, I first came across it ?10 years ago.

Comment: Yes, that's consistent with the link I provided, which was an organized competition 9 years ago.

Comment: @Richard: It started way earlier even, with APL.

Answer (score 3):

a complete waste of time and pixels - on SO [please people, leave this stuff on codegolf.com where it belongs; leave SO for *useful* questions]

Comment: @Steven, it can be useful for sharpening skills, personally I prefer these questions to "what is your favorite IDE color scheme"

Comment: While I agree that it is more useful than "what is your favorite IDE color scheme" I do not think that makes it useful for the site. If you want to sharpen your skills, go find someone's intractable problem and help them solve it.

Comment: **why whine about it?** It would take fewer keystrokes to add "code-golf" to you **Ignored tags** list than it did to write your mini-rant.

Comment: @[Sam Saffron]: "what is your favorite IDE color scheme" I can close as not-programming-related - and I would; code-golf is technically a programming question so I can't in good faith vote to close it, but it is non-productive noise. @[Argalatry]: i forgot about ignored tags, i'll do that right away - but that does not alter the navel-gazing, bit-wasting, pixel-churning, pocket-pool nature of code-golf questions on SO :-P

Comment: @[Argalatyr]: ignored meta-code-golf as well, thanks again for the reminder!

Comment: "A waste of pixels". Never heard that one before. Are we running out? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Code golf is for those bored of helping people solve real problems, but don't want to leave the site.

As per my comment, while I agree that it is more useful than some of the questions floated (the aforementioned "what is your favorite IDE color scheme" comes to mind) I do not think that makes it useful for the site.

If you want to sharpen your skills, go find someone's intractable problem and help them solve it.

Comment: This looks very much like a comment, not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a puzzle-style problem, which is a classic playground for programmers. A puzzle-style problem relating to programming is like chocolate for your girlfriend...it's not even a question of whether it'll be wanted. :-)