# Why is Code Golf a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion

I'm fairly new to the Stack Exchange network, and I really like the Q&A format used here, which is very clear to read and to use.

I started exploring all the sites, and I found there's a Code Golf site (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), but it doesn't seem to be a Q&A site, but rather a contest site, which seems to go against what the Stack Exchange sites represent.

So, why does this site exist in the network? Wouldn't it be more suitable in a different kind of site?

Please note that I do enjoy the site (I read the challenges every day although I've never sent an answer), but I'm curious about the issue.

Comment: Also see [puzzling.se].

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214070/) is relevant.

Comment: Sometimes people need to have a cool place to chill out, that's why those sites exist! Strictly speaking though, Puzzling.SE is about asking questions and getting answers. So is Code Golf.SE, but the people there just make answering competitive ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237130/programming-puzzles-code-golf-does-not-fit-in-stack-exchange?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, all of you. I was looking at it in a different way.