# What does it mean when question is tagged as code golf question?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “code golf” on stack overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/what-is-code-golf-on-stack-overflow)

Hi,

I am been using Stackoverflow for quite few time now and recently my question was given comment as code golf questions ? and I was not quite sure of what actually it is and so I wanted to know what does it mean when question is been marked as code golf question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/what-is-code-golf-on-stack-overflow). Also, you should try to search (Meta) Stack Overflow before asking a question - it might have already been asked (like this case).