# Editing at tee time, should we include a link to articulate code golf?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737947/code-golf-permutations/1737969#1737969). I'm wondering if code golf challenges should directly spell out their purpose by linking [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/what-is-code-golf-on-stack-overflow) or perhaps [here](http://codegolf.com/). This might help people avoid over thinking and partake in a little fun?

Would anyone mind if I edited existing challenges for clarification, if not, which link would be most appropriate?

I.e.

**This question describes a contest, please read {link} this {/link} prior to answering.**

Comment: Link no work, Waage not know what to do!

Comment: Dobee ironed his hands. Link is implied, not broken.

Comment: It'd be better if you had something more contextual than "this". Unless you're going for Fark.

Comment: @random, s/This/The\ following/ ?

Comment: If there is a reasonable level of agreement on this add it to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions

Comment: 'Course, I would argue that this happens because code-golf really doesn't belong, but I have long since lost that battle: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/so-weekly-code-golf

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is good as a recommended practice. I think it adds relevant information that I'm sure some people don't know immediately when a question is just described as "code golf". And if you get some level of agreement here on the principle, I think it would be appropriate to add that phrasing to old questions if you want to spend the time doing so.